# Is it possible to level up several levels at once in Ingress?

Tags: ingress

Let's suppose that L1 agent luckily destroys enemy portal with dosens of links and fields and gets huge AP boost that exceeds L3 AP Threshold.

Will he level up to L3 at once or just to L2 wasting excessive AP?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your AP is a continuous value. In other words, when you reach 10,000 AP and go to level 2, your AP bar doesn't reset to 0. It stays at 10,000 and in order to reach level 3, you need 30,000 AP. This means that you don't actually need to earn 30,000 AP. Instead, you need to earn 20,000.

So **yes**, you would level up twice.

Comment: Also note that when the level cap was 8 you kept collecting AP. Most players that had been around from the beginning instantaneously reached level 10 or more when the cap was raised.  The game not only kept track of all your AP gained (though it didn't count for anything) but also all actions, which went into the medals when those were introduced, so you had a bunch of medals show up at that point. Thus, leveling up multiple steps is possible indeed. Not on higher levels though. You always need more than just one medal more for above 8, so it's not possible to jump several steps then.

Comment: actually @simbabque it is possible to multiple level up beyond L8. Like, if you have 2 platinum badges (recharger, guardian) and 17M AP you can jump even from L10 to L14

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is also possible (and quite common) another way, jumping from 12 to 14.

If you already have 17M AP, and two platinum medals (agent can have recharger and gardian quite early) but only 6 gold medals, you are lvl 12. When you gain another gold medal you jump to lvl 14.

In this case, oddly, your scanner first displays the lvl 14 level up, then the lvl 13 one.